# div not expanding height with height auto

Tags: css

I'm just a little lost here, I am not understanding why the height of the container div doesn't change when the inner divs are bigger. In the image below, doctorAppointments(purple background) is the container div, and slotWrapper(selected background) is the inner div with bigger height.
[image]

Here is the CSS:

```
    .doctorAppointments{
    margin-left: auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 500px;
    min-width: 480px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: purple;
}

.slotWrapper{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    background-color: khaki;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue, a higher level div, the one wrapping all the rest of the divs, had a fixed height limiting the expansion.